# DynamoDB console does not show 'query' checkbox anymore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to query DynamoDB from AWS DynamoDB console, as it described at AWS manual, page 38:

```
http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/dynamodb/2011-12-05/dynamodb-dg-2011-12-05.pdf
```

I do not know the exact key and I'm going to query by key containing specific regular expression.

I open specific table and go to "Browse items".
Then I expect to see "Query" checkbox. 
Instead of it I see only "Get" checkbox. "Get" looks very similar to "Query", but it allows search by exact key only.

How can I get the "Query" menu with search by range key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> DynamoDB console does not show 'query' checkbox anymore

The UI in the DynamoDB console has been updated since this document was produced.

> I open specific table and go to "Browse items". Then I expect to see "Query" checkbox. Instead of it I see only "Get" checkbox. "Get" looks very similar to "Query", but it allows search by exact key only.

DynamoDB is not SQL, so words like "Query" mean something different. You're looking for "Scan" instead. You can read about the difference between [Query and Scan Operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html).

In the AWS Console, they don't expose a UI for searching using the Scan Operation. Instead they only do a "Scan All" operation and return the first 1 MB of results. To execute a search on DynamoDB, it appears that you'll either need to use [one of the SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/code), or the [CLI tools](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Or write your own.